# Does it ever make sense to use "been being" in a sentence?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, passive-voice

What is the passive form of the sentence

"You should have been telling John while I was outside" ?

I want to go with "John should have been being told while I was outside", but I think it sounds a bit unusual.

Comment: I would suggest that if you want to "go with" that you should take it to [ell.se]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not recommend it. It is awkward and unnecessary.

Your example is not good as "to tell" is ambitransitive and implies an object.

"John should... have .....been...{(being.....told) the story}........while I was outside"

S......modal....aux.inf......pp.....{(gerund....pp).......obj..}

.................................................{......NP predicate.........}

**Being told etc** is a gerund phrase acting as the substantive predicate / complement to "He should have been."

e.g.
**Being told** is a good way of learning the answer.

A: Why is the prisoner late? B: "He should **have been being beaten**, but the guards took him to the pub."

Have you been **being good(adj.phr.)** while I was out?

In practice, as (i) "while I was outside" implies the duration, and (ii) is a durative verb, so the gerund phrase is not actually required to indicate a continuing action.

If you want the passive, your *"John should have been being told the story while I was outside"* is good.

That said, imagine that the mother goes out and leaves her older daughter and young son at home. She tells the daughter to read John a story whilst she is outside and then put him to bed. When she returns the son is not in bed:

Mother: *"What are you doing?"*

Daughter: *"I am reading John the story."*

Mother: *"Well, you can stop now and put him to bed. John should have been being read the story by you whilst I was out, not when I returned."*

Again - do not use this, there are some passive constructions that should not be used other than colloquially.

Comment: I'm not a fan of your parsing.  This is a verb concatenation all the way through. Your example is a gerund phrase, but I don't score the OP's as a gerund phrase. "A nuisance is what I have been being", not "Being a nuisance is what I have been." The idea here is to preserve the continuous aspect in a past setting. A pp + continuous aux is what I see.

Comment: @PhilSweet In retrospect, you could right. I was torn between the two and came down on one side. Of the two examples you give, the latter is the one I'd choose as your "being" is a linking verb, but the example "being" seems to equate more to to be's sense of "to spend time" (I have been in Paris.)